# WPF: draw on one panel in foreground of another panel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm building a windows app in wpf. I have a stackpanel containing a WindowsFormsHost which receives a stream of images. Even if I place on top of another stackPanel, it fades into the background. I have already tried using Panel.ZIndex.

```
 <StackPanel  x:Name="drawPanel2"  Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="1" Panel.ZIndex="0" >
            <WindowsFormsHost Background="Black" Height="720"  x:Name="winforms_host" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="540" Panel.ZIndex="0"/>
        </StackPanel>


        <StackPanel x:Name="drawPanel" Orientation="Horizontal" Panel.ZIndex="1" Grid.Column="1">
            <Rectangle Height="200"  Width="540" Fill="AliceBlue" Panel.ZIndex="1"/>
        </StackPanel>
```

be able to place a rectangle above the windowsformsHost output

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9920480/1136211, https://stackoverflow.com/q/1007743/1136211, https://stackoverflow.com/q/6087835/1136211